# Which RGB profile should be used when exporting a PDF for web?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, rgb, color-profile, color-conversion

I created a 60 page book in CMYK because it is going to be printed. I now need to convert this document to RGB so it can be viewed online. From doing a little research on this site, I see that I can change the color profile as I am exporting the PDF, and not have to individually convert the photos and swatches as I originally feared.

When I went to export and change the color profile, I noticed that there are a few sRGB options. The following may seem like a silly question, but I want to make absolutely sure I'm selecting the right profile. Which sRGB profile do I need to use: Document RGB, Working RGB, or just sRGB?

[image: sRGB Options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all the same profile. The name of the profile is `sRGB IEC61966-2.1`. The other labels are just where they are set:

- Working RGB says your program is using that RGB mode. Yes you can work in a space that does not reflect the document setting.
- Document RGB says the document is specifying that RGB mode.

They are all the same profile though and result in same thing.

Anyway I dont really see the point in converting the doc to RGB for web. That is unless you plan to adjust the colors after the conversion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by adjusting the colors after conversion? When we were sending a CMYK-based file around for proofreading, some people were viewing them on iPads, etc. and the colors were obviously completely off. I just want to make sure that when we put this book online, people aren't going to be seeing crazy colors because it's not set in the right color profile.

Comment: @SJF colors are always off after conversion, therefore one customarily compensates this with slight human eye correction. Anyway it is the job of the viewer to handle profile conversions, and any good viewer should produce exactly the same effect as your conversion assuming your profile intent is the same. So given that everything is the same you should get same results with and without conversion. Unless your actually trying to circumvent a bug in a viewer. Colors on a non-calibrated/profiled device is a hit and miss anyway.