# What is the difference between Working RGB and Document RGB when exporting a PDF from InDesign CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, cs5

I'm using InDesign CS5, sometimes my export setting gets stuck on CMYK mode as I was working on a different document previously and when exporting the PDF setting is saved.

No problem, I just go to Output and change it to RGB.  Usually I choose either Working RGB or Document RGB, but I don't really know the difference.  Can anyone help me to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had asked a similar question to this a few months ago, and @joojaa gave me [this helpful answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58588/which-rgb-profile-should-be-used-when-exporting-a-pdf-for-web):

They are all the same profile. The name of the profile is sRGB IEC61966-2.1. The other labels are just where they are set:

- Working RGB says your program is using that RGB mode. Yes you can
  work in a space that does not reflect the document setting.
- DocumentRGB says the document is specifying that RGB mode.

They are all the same profile though and result in same thing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see, so there is no preference?  Is document slightly better if I send it to other people?  I assume Document RGB makes the file size slightly larger which may also be another consideration?  Thanks for the answer, very hlepful.

Comment: @Eoin Document profile is the only thing that is stored in the long run. Working is just the space where you work in data is still in document space you just see all values in working space numbers.